# After Deleting Row, Unable to Reload UITableView Data from NSObject File

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsobject

When Pressing delete button it deletes selected Object from WebServer Datasource but unable to reload TableView,

> Here is my code, Please advice that how to accomplish this or to let
>   me know where I am doing this wrong.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Records * RecordsObject;

    RecordsObject = [recordsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = RecordsObject.recordsMname;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text= RecordsObject.recordsImei;

    UIButton *detailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [detailButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    detailButton.frame = CGRectMake(WidthCalculation - 45, 0.0f, 50.0f, 45.0f);
    [cell addSubview:detailButton];
    [detailButton addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(detailsButton:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:detailButton];
    [detailButton setTag:indexPath.row];


    UIButton *deleteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [deleteButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"trash"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    deleteButton.frame = CGRectMake(WidthCalculation - 75, 0.0f, 50.0f, 45.0f);
    [cell addSubview:deleteButton];
    [deleteButton addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(delButton:event:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [cell.contentView addSubview:deleteButton];



    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Delete Button Functionality

```
- (IBAction)delButton: (UIButton*)button event:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UIButton *delButton = button;
    NSLog(@"FaceBook Button is sharing %li row's Image", (long)delButton.tag);

    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:
                              [[[event touchesForView:button] anyObject]
                               locationInView:self.tableView]];

    Records *object = self.recordsArray[delButton.tag];
    NSLog(@"selected Object %@", object);
    NSString *id = object.recordsId;
    NSMutableString * postString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:kdeleteURL];
    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@", kId, id]];
    [postString setString:[postString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request =[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postString]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    postConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
    [self.recordsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            [self.tableView reloadData];


}
```

Please do let me know if you require more information such is as code for object file or data retrieval code snippet for retrieving data from server side.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSIndexPath *index = [[NSIndexPath alloc] init];

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Records * RecordsObject;

    RecordsObject = [recordsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = RecordsObject.recordsMname;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text= RecordsObject.recordsImei;

    UIButton *detailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [detailButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    detailButton.frame = CGRectMake(WidthCalculation - 45, 0.0f, 50.0f, 45.0f);
    [cell addSubview:detailButton];
    [detailButton addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(detailsButton:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:detailButton];
    [detailButton setTag:indexPath.row];


    UIButton *deleteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [deleteButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"trash"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    deleteButton.frame = CGRectMake(WidthCalculation - 75, 0.0f, 50.0f, 45.0f);
    deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row
    [cell addSubview:deleteButton];
    [deleteButton addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(delButton:event:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [cell.contentView addSubview:deleteButton];



    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)delButton: (UIButton*)button event:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UIButton *delButton = button;
    NSLog(@"FaceBook Button is sharing %li row's Image", (long)delButton.tag);

    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:
                              [[[event touchesForView:button] anyObject]
                               locationInView:self.tableView]];

    Records *object = self.recordsArray[delButton.tag];
    NSLog(@"selected Object %@", object);
    NSString *id = object.recordsId;
    NSMutableString * postString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:kdeleteURL];
    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@", kId, id]];
    [postString setString:[postString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request =[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postString]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    postConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
    index = indexPath
}
```

If you get success response then delete row and object from array.

```
-(void)serviceResponce() {
   [self.recordsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject: index] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```